# Grafana Provisioning Notification Channels not working

Tags: docker, grafana

I am trying to build a Docker container with existing datasources, dashboards and notification channels. The provisioning of datasources and dashboards are working but not the provisioning of Notification Channels. Using Grafana v6.3.5 (commit: 67bad72)

I am using the example config from the Grafana Provisioning documentation. I have added it to the `/etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers` directory to a file called `AlertNotificationChannel.yaml`

I can see it is processing the file because I can see a message "Deleting alert notification logger=provisioning.notifiers name=notification-channel-1 uid=notifier1" in the logs. However no messages about inserting or updating alert notification and nothing in UI.

Contents of yaml file:

```
notifiers:
  - name: notification-channel-1
    type: slack
    uid: notifier1
    # either
    org_id: 2
    # or
    org_name: Main Org.
    is_default: true
    send_reminder: true
    frequency: 1h
    disable_resolve_message: false
    # See `Supported Settings` section for settings supporter for each
    # alert notification type.
    settings:
      recipient: "XXX"
      token: "xoxb"
      uploadImage: true
      url: https://slack.com

delete_notifiers:
  - name: notification-channel-1
    uid: notifier1
    # either
    org_id: 2
    # or
    org_name: Main Org.
```

I believe this functionality was added after v5 of Grafana and I am trying to follow the documentation but not working.

Answer (score 2):

So I was having the same issue for a little bit today and I was able to make it work. I want to guess that you ended up finding a solution but I find it useful to post an example of something that works for future people going through this issue. The reason nothing was appearing in the UI is probably cause they were a mistake somewhere.

This is an example of my docker-compose:

```
grafana:
      image: grafana/grafana
      container_name: grafana
      restart: always
      user: "0"
      ports:
          - "3000:3000"
      volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: "/root/Docker/grafana/grafana"
            target: "/var/lib/grafana"
          - type: bind
            source: "/root/Docker/grafana/provisioning"
            target: "/etc/grafana/provisioning"
```

This is an example of my "/grafana/provisioning/notifiers/slack.yml"

```
notifiers:
  - name: slack-alarming
    type: slack
    username: Grafa_Alert
    is_default: true
    send_reminder: true
    org_name: LML
    settings:
      uploadImage: true
      url: POSTHOOKURL from slack
```

Note that the org Name is the name of my company and the username is random.

Thanks,

Wassim